# If $|f_n|\le S_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges uniformly, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f_n:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded and nonnegative functions, with $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $S_n:=\sup\{f_n(x):x\in D\}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges uniformly, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S_n$ converge?

I think it's true. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can find $x_n\in D$ such that $S_n-1/2^n<f_n(x_n)$. Then we have $\sum_{i=1}^nS_i<\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x_i)+\sum_{i=1}^n1/2^i$.

The sequence $\sum_{i=1}^n1/2^i$ is bounded. However, I don't know if $\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x_i)$ is bounded since the $x_i$ are not the same.

Would anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Hint: $\sum S_n$ may diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $(0,1),$ define $f_n(x)= (1/n)\chi_{[1/(n+1),1/n)}.$ Then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly on $(0,1),$ but $S_n = 1/n$ for each $n,$ hence $\sum S_n = \infty.$

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.